# Failed to find matching element please file bug

Tags: ios, xcode, xctest, ui-testing

When using the "Record UI Test" feature in Xcode, I was getting

> Failed to find matching element please file bug

This was despite it working earlier in the same session. I was also getting timeouts on `waitForExpectationsWithTimeout` when I hand-rolled the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The upshot is I was trying to find a cell in a table that was about to be presented. I wanted to set the table's `accessibilityIdentifier` to make it easier to find. After Googling to confirm it needed to be done in code rather than IB, I found a post suggesting I also needed to set

```
    tableView.isAccessibilityElement = true
```

I didn't realise it all stopped working the minute I did that, because I made other changes as well. Once this property was set, I could no longer find any cells/staticTexts within the table. When I commented the code out, it all started magically working again, including recording tests.

Comment: Same issue, thanks for posting your solution. Did you filled a bug for that ? so that I can duplicate the radar

Comment: I didn't because I felt it was just a catch-all error and I was probably doing something wrong. Particularly because nobody else seemed to have a similar problem.

Comment: Indeed ^^ seems like few people are hitting this problem. I will flag a radar tomorrow to notify Apple. I'll keep you posted.